# StreamBuilder inside the ListviewBuilder not scrolling

Tags: flutter

**Problem:**    I am beginner for flutter developing. I tried to get data from firestore and display it. But scrolling listview didn't respond to one finger so I had to use more than one. How to solve this problem.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: _firebase_auth.collection("ContactData").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemExtent: 100.0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
              return Card(
                child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), children: [
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                ]),
              );
            });
      } else {
        return Text('Loading Data.....');
      }
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line in listView.builder

```
physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: I used it but same output. Thanks for help.

Comment: try NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: I solved it. used  warping stream builder with SingleChildScrolView, set ListviewBuilder shrinkWrap: true, physics: ScrollPhysics() and set ListView physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() now work perfect. Thansk for help.

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap streamBuilder with the SingleChild scroll view or use shrinkWrap: true,physics: ScrollPhysics(),

```
body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: _firebase_auth.collection("ContactData").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemExtent: 100.0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
              return Card(
                child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), children: [
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                  Text('sds'),
                ]),
              );
            });
      } else {
        return Text('Loading Data.....');
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: I used both but same out. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap stream builder with `SingleChildScrolView`.

*This will make the screen a scrollable element.*

- Set physics of `ListView.builder` to `NeverScrollablePhysics`.

*This will prevent the scrolling of the parent ListView.Builder, but it's okay because it's parent, `SingleChildScrollView` is
scrollable.*

- Set physics of `ListView` to `Scrollable`

*If you want to, not sure if you want to scroll these items or just display*.

Comment: yeah. I want scroll items. I solved it. used  warping stream builder with SingleChildScrolView, set ListviewBuilder shrinkWrap: true, physics: ScrollPhysics() and set ListView physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() now work perfect. Thansk for help.

Comment: If this solved your question, kindly consider marking it as the correct answer to your post, thanks.